# Kivy: Algining BoxLayout to the right of another BoxLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to align a BoxLayout to the upper right of another BoxLayout, but I can only get it to appear underneath the first BoxLayout.

[image: This is what I have at the moment:]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I've read from similar questions this can be done with pos_hint, but no combination of pos_hints currently let me do this.

My current KV code is as follow:

```
<DashboardScreen>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex("#0b172e")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Spacer:
        size_hint: (1, 0.04)
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (0.98, 0.90)
        pos_hint: {"right": 0.99}
        
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (0.03, 0.9)
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex("#1b203e")
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Spacer:
                size_hint: (0.3, 1)
        
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (0.8, 0.35)
            pos_hint: {"right": 0.99}
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.99}
            spacing: "5"
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex("#1b203e")
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `orientation` of the enclosing `BoxLayout` to `horizontal`:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint: (0.98, 0.90)
    pos_hint: {"right": 0.99}
```